# Column name with "." to be replaced with "_" using Python

Tags: python, json

Below code reads a JSON file and stores it into DB Table.
But few column names are generated with `"."`.
Only these particular column names has to be replaced with underscore `"_"`. If at all `"."` is encountered in any column names before pushing to table. Data shouldn't be changed, but only column names with `"."` to `"_"` in my python code.

Below is what I tried and not sure how to replace the column names and then push to DB:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import sys
import psycopg2
 
data = sys.argv[1]
user= sys.argv[2]
password = sys.argv[3]
host = sys.argv[4]
port = sys.argv[5]
db = sys.argv[6]
documenttype = sys.argv[7]
schema_name =  sys.argv[8]

from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://'+user+':'+password+'@'+host+':'+port+'/'+db)
print("Database is connected")

df = pd.read_json(data)

df['RecordsNew'] = df['Records'].astype('|S80')

df_1 = pd.json_normalize(df['Records'])
df_1.columns = map(str.lower, df_1.columns)
table_name =documenttype.lower()

df_1.to_sql(table_name,schema=schema_name,con=engine, if_exists = 'append',index=False)
```

JSON code example:

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "CommodityId": "3470",
      "SourceSystem": "SSP-generic-CHILD4",
      "CommodityName": "ANCHOR BOLTS - BILL OF MATERIALS",
      "CommodityType": ""
    },
    {
      "CommodityId": "468657",
      "SourceSystem": "SSP-generic-CHILD4",
      "CommodityName": "COOLING INSERT",
      "CommodityType": ""
    },
    {
      "CommodityId": "836519",
      "SourceSystem": "SSP-generic-CHILD4",
      "CommodityName": "DIAPHRAGM 2ND STAGE PGT25",
      "CommodityType": ""
    },
    {
      "CommodityId": "807525",
      "SourceSystem": "SSP-generic-CHILD4",
      "CommodityName": "MOBILE NOZZLE MACHINING 2ST MS5002C(S2N)",
      "CommodityType": ""
      "ReconciledBy":{"SourceSystem":"SSP-sap-CHILD1","UserId":"","PasswordAdapter":""}
    },
    ...
  ],
  "PageToken": "TlhXQ0FVcTlzNE8rQQ"
}
```

Example of column names generated with "."

```
"reconciledby.passwordadapter"
"procurementunit.sourcesystem"
"procurementunit.uniquename"
"sourcesystem.sourcesystemid"
```

Comment: Where are the columns stored in JSON?

Comment: In the Json (Updated) if you can see there's a column ReconciledBy and writes it as reconciledby.passwordadapter into the table as a column name. This has to be reconciledby_passwordadapter, similarly for other columns with . too